# unable to render JSON/JSONSchema. Invalid member type of object in MSON definition

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

I have API documentation and suddenly without any changes it started throwing validation alert `unable to render JSON/JSONSchema. Invalid member type of object in MSON definition` at Response 200 (application/json) line.

```
+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Attributes (Restaurant Full)
```

I tried to google it but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Apiary*

The message suggests there is an error in Restaurant Full object definition - one of the members has an invalid type.

This error is related to object type members, primitive types do not yield this. For instance - it would be thrown if you define an object type member with a string sample value like this:

```
+ Attributes (Restaurant Full):
    + `invalid-member-type`: sample value (object)
```

If this doesn't resolve your issue, could you post your definition of the Restaurant Full object?

Comment: Actually I had `nil` as sample value for one property. Thanks for the help!